# How to I extract a range of values from a numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

so far I have:

```
import numpy as np
import random
dimension = int(input("Enter the number of rows and columns: \n")) 
randomMatrix = np.random.randint(0,16, size=(dimension,dimension))
print(randomMatrix)
x = input("please select the parameters of which you want to extract an array:")
y = input("please enter the second parameter:")
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
print(randomMatrix[:, x:y])
```

however, it never prints the desired range. Basically, I want to generate a random matrix with user defined dimensions and then print a range of rows and columns specified by the user. However it only ever prints one column and nothing else. Furthermore, I am not sure if this is a matrix or array, and I'm not sure how to preoceed with this problem if it were an array, theres probably some numpy shenanigans you can do with arrays to get the desired result. ANy help is appreciated :)

Comment: If you want to select *rows*, not columns, you have to slice the first axis: `randomMatrix[x:y, :]`

Comment: I want to print both rows and columns in a user specified dimension, how do I do that?

Comment: @PythonSux -- Looked at your comments beneath your question and beneath other answer. You really need to edit your question to provide some more detail, to clearly write down what were the exact user inputs you had entered, and for those user inputs, what was the random matrix that got generated, the exact outputs that you were expecting, and the exact outputs that you actually got. I don't see this going anywhere without those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine for me. However, you might want to add some checks to your code. To slice both dimensions

```
x = input("please select the parameters of which you want to extract an array:")
y = input("please enter the second parameter:")
x = int(x)
y = int(y)

x_row = int(input("please select the rows of which you want to extract an array:"))
y_row = int(input("please enter the second number for row:"))
```

I edited below part based on the comments:

```
if x == y:
    print(randomMatrix[x_row:y_row, x])
elif x_row == y_row:
    print(randomMatrix[x_row, x:y])
elif x == y and x_row == y_row:
    print(randomMatrix[x_row, x])
else:
    print(randomMatrix[x_row:y_row, x:y])
```

Hope it works.

Comment: however when I do that, it doesnt print the range it just returns [ ].

Comment: what values did you assign to `x, y, x_row, y_row` ? then we have to go from exact values...

Comment: the values of x, y, x_row, y_row are to be queried by the user.

Comment: give me an example then, a set of numbers you suppose a user has entered

Comment: so first the user gives the dimension for a randomly generated array, and then he gives the dimensions for a certain range of that matrix to be "extracted" per se. So if the range of the matrix is 6:6, and the user gives in 2:3, I want it to print the first 2 values of the row and the 3 values from the column, printing a smaller matrix

Comment: will do but i have under 15 reputation so my upvote wont be displayed publicly